# jquery plug-ins conflict resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm  just trying to find out if there is any way to trace/findout jquery plugin conflicts without going much deeper into the code or at least some kind of test   that can be done to make sure that there isn't any conflict among different jquery plugins.

Also how to fix them other than noConflict approach. thanks

Comment: do you mean something specific saying "jquery plugins conflict" ?

Comment: What plugins are you using, how do we know the issue, are there more than one library used i mean jQuery, prototype or yui etc.

Comment: there is only one JQuery library... and no specific plugin. I'm doing it for educational purposes. Supposing there are conflicting Jquery plugins two or more.. anyway i can know it for sure which one are conflicting and how to resolve them without using noConflict AND I don't want to edit any plugin code either ... some tool or anything